# i need to create a ticket with number like = 0000 and every time code executed it should increase by 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a code which will increase ticket number every time it's executed. Numbers should start from 0000, second call - 0001, third - 0002 ...

```
num=[0000]
num.append
print(f'* N° Ticket : {num}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have some helpful answers already, but it would still help to [edit] the question and clarify what exactly you need help with, whether it's saving the current number to a file, incrementing the number, adding leading zeroes (cause `0000` is invalid), etc. Read [ask] for more pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've surprised, that noone actually noticed that "problem" described in question requires saving of state.*

You can save number of last ticket in file.

```
from pathlib import Path

FN = "ticket.dat"

with open(FN, "r+b" if Path(FN).exists() else "w+b") as f:  # create file if it doesn't exist
    tmp = f.read()  # read content from file
    last_ticket_number = int.from_bytes(tmp, "big") if tmp else 0
    print(f"{last_ticket_number:04d}")
    last_ticket_number += 1
    f.seek(0)  # go back to the start of file to rewrite it
    f.write(last_ticket_number.to_bytes(last_ticket_number.bit_length() // 8 + 1, "big"))
```

---

Explanation:

- `open(FN, "r+b" if Path(FN).exists() else "w+b")`

  `FN` contains name of file. [`Path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists) check if file already exists.

  So, if file `ticket.dat` already exist, we open it with mode `r+b`, which allow us both reading and writing, **BUT** it'll throw error if file doesn't exist. That's why we will use `w+b` in case if file haven't been created yet.

  Quote from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

  > For binary read-write access, the mode `'w+b'` opens and truncates the file to 0 bytes. `'r+b'` opens the file without truncation.
- `int.from_bytes(tmp, "big") if tmp else 0`

  We open file in binary more, that's why `f.read()` will return [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes). To convert them into `int` we use [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).

  If `f.read()` return nothing (file have just been created) we set `0` as number of first ticket.
- `last_ticket_number.to_bytes(last_ticket_number.bit_length() // 8 + 1, "big")`

  As we work with file in binary mode, we need to pass `bytes` into `f.write()`. We use [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes). It requires argument `length`.

  To calculate length in bytes we use [`int.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length). It returns length of int variable in bits.

Comment: thanks your code worked for me and i solved the problem with this
`ba=open("c.txt", "r")
num=ba.read()
num=int(num)
num2=num+1
num2=str(num2)
ba.close
ba=open('c.txt','w')
ba.write(num2)
ba.close
ba=open("c.txt", "r")
num=ba.read()
num=int(num)
ba.close`

Comment: @BilalZeghari, you've done it using text mode, which is also possible way.

Answer (score 0):

Use format to specify padding, sample:

```
print('* N° Ticket : {0:04}'.format(num))
```

Try this

```
for i in range(1000):
  print('* N° Ticket : {0:04}'.format(i))
```

One liner:

```
print('\n'.join('* N° Ticket : {0:04}'.format(i) for i in  range(1000)))
```

Put your range in place of 1000

.zfill() is used for strings, for numbers, .format() is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
num=0
def ticket():
    global num
    num+=1
    s=str(num).zfill(4)
    return s


print(f'* N° Ticket',ticket())
print(f'* N° Ticket',ticket())
print(f'* N° Ticket',ticket())
print(f'* N° Ticket',ticket())
```

Output:

```
* N° Ticket 0001
* N° Ticket 0002
* N° Ticket 0003
* N° Ticket 0004
```

Comment: thanks i solved my problem with creating a text file contain 0000 and read it and save it as variable then add 1 to the value and write it in file then read value again and use it in my program because my problem was how can i add +1 to the value everytime i restart program to use it again

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_seq(seq):
    return '%04d' % (int(seq) +1 )

seq = '0000'
seq = get_seq(seq)
print(seq)
```

If you need to increase digit number , just update in `get_seq` method. Update digit number instead of 4. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i created a file named c.txt contain 0000

```
ba=open("c.txt", "r")
num=ba.read()
num=int(num)
num2=num+1
num2=str(num2)
ba.close
ba=open('c.txt','w')
ba.write(num2)
ba.close
ba=open("c.txt", "r")
num=ba.read()
num=int(num)
ba.close
```